# Merge two strings with preg_match and strlen

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, strlen

Example text:

```
Vind vid marken 
Område 1c: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand S/15-20 
knop, byar upp till 35 knop. 
Område 1a: S/10-20 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 
knop. 
Område 2c,3d: SO/10-15 knop. 
Område 1b: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 
knop, byar upp till 30 knop. 
Område 2a,2b,3a,3b,3c: SO/5-10 knop, efterhand SO/10-15 knop.
```

I get this text from another webpage and I want to get ridd of the fifth line "knop.".
It's too short to make any difference on the output width and only clutters the data.

I loop through each line one at the time and at the end echo it.

I thought I could use preg_match to find out if the word "knop" is in the NEXT line and if the NEXT line is less than 7 char.
And if this is true merge them and keep going.
I'm still struggling with the if() so the code in the if may or may not be correct.

```
if (preg_match("/knop./", $Lines[$i+1]) && 1*strlen($Lines[$i+1] < 7)) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . 1*strlen($Lines[$i+1]) . '"); </script>';
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . 1*strlen($Lines[$i+1]) . '"); </script>';
  echo "<h1>" . $Lines[$i+1] . "</h1>";
  $Lines[$i] = trim($Lines[$i]) . " " .       $Lines[($i+1)]; //                        unset($Lines[($i+1)]); 
}
```

I have the alerts and echo H1 only to debug.
The odd thing is that the if reacts on a line that is 72 char long.

I obviously am doing something wrong, I have figured that out... ;-)

Comment: `strlen($Lines[$i+1] < 7)` should be `strlen($Lines[$i+1]) < 7` (and yeah, what chris said)

Comment: You have Unicode characters in the string, use `mb_strlen` and `/u` modifier with `preg_match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole text (multi line) in one string, and then you can use this regular expression on it to clean it up:

```
// Get all text in one variable first (only needed if you do not have this yet)
$text = implode("\n", $Lines); 
// Move short lines to the end of previous lines
$text = preg_replace('#\h*\R(.{0,2}knop\.)\h*(\R|$)#', " $1\n", $text);
// rebuild Lines variable.
$Lines = explode("\n", $text);
```

Some explanation of the *preg_replace* regular expression and replacement:

- It requires a previous line to be present with `\R`;
- It allows up to two free characters to precede "knop." (you can play with this 2 to allow more or less);
- It allows spaces to occur after "knop." with `\h` (horizontal white space);
- After "knop." and some optional blanks the line must end: `\R` or `$` (end)
- The replacement takes care that "knop." is appended to the previous line with exactly one space between it and the last word of the previous line.

Note that if you `echo` text containing `\n` to a browser, it will not show line-breaks at those positions, but just a space, producing the output in one long line. To force the browser to show `\n` as line-break, wrap the output in `pre` tags, like this:

```
echo "<pre>$text</pre>";
```

Comment: I do have the full text. 
The problem is that it's very long. The part I gave you guys here is the "problem" area.
I can implode, or just do it before. Maybe. Not sure what code like this will do to the rest of the text. Will look at that first.

Comment: If you have the whole text in one long string variable, then the `preg_replace` on that variable will be the most efficient solution, as I described in my answer. Have you tried?

Comment: No sorry not yet. I tried it as my code is currently (an array with one line per key) but it didn't work as expected. I will try it later when I have time.

Comment: I can't make any of yours preg_replace to work. Have a look at my code please. [link](http://www.hoppvader.nu/php.txt) The echo becomes a wall of text.

Comment: When you `echo` to a browser, make sure to wrap the output in `pre` tags, because a browser normally renders "\n" as a normal horizontal space. In `pre` tags it works for me. I also notice you have phrases ending with things like "FL100: ", which maybe you want to have treated in a similar way?

Comment: I added in my answer the note about rendering `\n` in a browser. Is your purpose to output the text in a browser? Would you then accept a solution where the text wrapping is taken care of by a `div` element in the web page? I could suggest something like that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I forgot to add $Lines = explode.... on the last line of code in the txt file i linked to above. Silly mistake. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by the FL100? It's actually the start of the string. It means on 100.000 ft (altitude) the winds and temperatur is blabla....

Comment: Forget my comment about `FL100`. I understand it now.  However, I still wonder if you would not prefer a nicer HTML-enriched output, with `h1`, `h2` tags and such.

Comment: I see your point. It may happen. Not to hard to fix that. However the text is (depending on the users preference) highlighted if it has significance to him/her. You can have a look at the settingspage picture, The first one. [link](http://www.hoppvader.nu/Settings.php) But I will look in to H tags in the text. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Sorry to see my answer being unaccepted after two days. Let me know what the problem was.

Comment: Sorry mate that was not my intention.
I was sure I accepted all three answers here. Sorry :-(

Comment: Indeed, you can only accept one. You can give an upvote to more than one, but only one can be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches every `knop` and one additional character. First escape the `.` because in regex that means any character.

Demo of current regex: https://regex101.com/r/xQ2eZ3/1

I would make your regex:

```
/^knop\.\h*$/m
```

which checks each line (because of the `m` modifier after the delimiter). The `\s*` is for horizontal whitespace after the `knop.`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xQ2eZ3/3

Another approach could be checking for a new line prior to the `knop.` and then replacing it if found. Also should check for the start and end of string. Then can use `preg_replace`.

```
/(?:^|\n)(knop\.\h*(?:\n|$))/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xQ2eZ3/5

**Update:**

```
$Result = preg_replace('/\v(knop\.\h*(\v|$))/', '$1', $Lines);
print_r(explode("\n", $Result));
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oJ3uB0/1

Note the usage of the replaced values in the explode as well.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/510853

Comment: Of course!
A dot is not a dot. Bugger.

I tried both of your regex. But none of them work.
I think it's because I didn't make it clear enough earlier that I explode the text to lines with \n as delimiter.
Since explode removes the delimiter both of them fail.

I will look at my posibilities to do this before exploding it. 
Not sure it will work.
Will look in to it and come back.

Comment: Oh, yes these were meant if the input was the whole string you provided. Do you need to explode or were you just doing that to run the regex line by line?

Comment: I need to explode. The next part of the code reads the text. Really.
It looks at each line and understands the line and if the area in the text is the one it's looking for it highlights it. It also understands if the text says all areas except [area] (and other variations of it). And highlights until next area begins. It's rather complex and not something I want to redo.

Comment: What about changing the order? Regex then explode?

Comment: Maybe. Thinking about it. Can not think of any reason it would cause problems. As mentioned in another comment this text is only part of the text. The other part of the text also uses the word "knop" often (knots as in windspeed if it is still unclear), that could cause problems. But shouldn't. That is why I want to look at the lenght of the line also. If it's less than 7 it's a short line with "knop" and merge, else don't merge.

Comment: I can't make any of yours preg_replace to work. Have a look at my code please. [link](http://www.hoppvader.nu/php.txt)  The echo becomes a wall of text.

Comment: Posted an update just incase it wasn't solved, and so answer is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the structure you've posted in itself is representative of all the texts you want to process, but I see a pattern emerging from the text. Rather than just checking if there's only `"knop."` in the line, you could of course choose to try to revert the wrapping, by concatenating strings from "Område" until the first occurrence of a full stop / period. This has the upside that you then manipulate the text in a way you see fit.

```
<?php
$text = <<<TEXT
Vind vid marken 
Område 1c: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand S/15-20 
knop, byar upp till 35 knop. 
Område 1a: S/10-20 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 
knop. 
Område 2c,3d: SO/10-15 knop. 
Område 1b: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 
knop, byar upp till 30 knop. 
Område 2a,2b,3a,3b,3c: SO/5-10 knop, efterhand SO/10-15 knop. 
I
TEXT;


$new = preg_replace_callback('~(Vind vid marken|(?:Område)(?:[^\.]+))\.~sm', function ($match) {
   // in $match[0], we have the entire line from the occurance of "Område" until a period ".".
   return str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $match[0]);
}, $text); 


var_dump(wordwrap($new, 80));
```

This yields the following:

```
string(383) "Vind vid marken 
Område 1c: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand S/15-20 knop, byar
upp till 35 knop. 
Område 1a: S/10-20 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop. 
Område 2c,3d: SO/10-15 knop. 
Område 1b: S/15-20 knop, byar upp till 30 knop, efterhand SO/15-20 knop, byar
upp till 30 knop. 
Område 2a,2b,3a,3b,3c: SO/5-10 knop, efterhand SO/10-15 knop. 
I"
```

Which seems to answer your question, just in a different way ;)

Comment: I think there may be more than one full stop sometimes.
It's a interesting idea. I had an idea earlier to explode on "Område".
This will also give me the full text on each area in one string.
So wordwrap( XX, 80) is 80 char til new line. 
Interesting.... Thanks